# Server receiving hit from its own DigitalOcean public IP Address. Why is that and how to resolve this?

Tags: server, nginx, linux, node-js

I have a MEAN Stack application deployed on a Digital Ocean Droplet and I am using Nginx as proxy server to handle the request and redirect to application's particular port.

I wrote a short script in node.js which fetches IP and location of the users visiting my website. I can see the searched queries and usage of my API from external users and are same as those I can see via Google Analytics.

But also **I am also getting a strange hit to my server (and API links) from my own IP Address**. Why is that?

Is that because of Nginx? 
Is this even an actual user or what?
Is it some DDOS Attack?
Is it any script executing itself on my own server?
Someone suggested that it might because of the Monitoring tool installed on your server. Can this be the reason as well or its something else?

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: When you say "proxy" do you mean a "reverse proxy"?  If so have you looked into passing the original IP address of the user through as a HTTP header?  The [nginx reverse proxy documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) says how.   Look at the  `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` directive that it describes.